# Python pip requirements file console scripts

Tags: python, ssl, pip, setuptools

Is there a way to have the equivalent of console_scripts found in setuptools setup.py into requirements.txt file used by pip install -r requirements.txt.

I'm tying to install from a non trusted ssl server a package.
The only way to make it work so far with a setup.py file is like this

`pip install -e .  -e git+https://gitlab/s/package.git#egg=package`

Where the gitlab server has a self signed cert. Into the setup.py I have some console scripts.

Answer (score 0):

first download the packages then install them from their local copy

```
git clone git@xxxxxxxx:package.git
pip install -e /my/folder/with/a/setup.py/inside
```